# Why does node mkdirSync() throw exception?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I am running node v4.2.0 on Windows 8. I have found that fs.mkdirSync() *occasionally* throws EPERM for no apparent reason.

I managed to recreate it with this test code, which I save in a file bug.js.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 100000; i += 1) {
    fs.mkdirSync("xx");
    fs.rmdirSync("xx");
}
```

This is the trace I *occasionally* get:

```
C:\WIP>node bug
C:\WIP\bug.js:0

    Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\WIP\xx'
        at Error (native)
        at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:799:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\WIP\bug.js:4:8)
        at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
        at startup (node.js:134:18)
        at node.js:961:3
```

It does not happen always, even with the 100000 loop. In fact its a slippery beast - if I run bug.js several times it seems to reduce the probability of hitting the exception. When I tried catching the exception I found that it was happening after many thousands of successful iterations of the loop.

Why does the exception occur? Is there any way to avoid the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a shortcoming of the windows system, you're probably just doing actions on a folder too fast and they start to overlap and throw those errors. Have you tried this on a linux system?

It is however very much likely to get a permission denied exception, if someone were to manually change the permissions. You should always put those kind of actions in a try{}catch{} block.

EDIT:

```
rquist@rquist-ThinkPad-T530 ~/projects $ vim app.js # Made your code here
rquist@rquist-ThinkPad-T530 ~/projects $ node app.js 
rquist@rquist-ThinkPad-T530 ~/projects $ node app.js 
rquist@rquist-ThinkPad-T530 ~/projects $ node app.js 
rquist@rquist-ThinkPad-T530 ~/projects $ node app.js 
rquist@rquist-ThinkPad-T530 ~/projects $ node app.js 
rquist@rquist-ThinkPad-T530 ~/projects $
```

Not getting any exceptions here on Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: I have not managed to recreate it on linux, so yes it feels like a Windows thing. I don't agree that you should _always_ use try{}catch{} around mkdirSync(). Sometimes your program needs to create a folder and has every right to expect it to work and has nowhere to go if it does not. Why shouldn't it work? I just did rmdirSync() - the last operation should be done and dusted with no overlaps.

Comment: My guess is that there is something in windows' filesystem management that breaks - maybe mkdir reported "Done" while it was still writing to the disk in the background, then the rm gets fired to a handle that isn't created yet / is being created, and thus you get the EPERM exception. But you're right - looking at the code this is a bug. The code is valid and should never throw an exception like this in this case. And yeah, if it can't function without that dir not catching it should do, but usually its a task that shouldn't stop your whole program. End of line - I agree, this is buggy.

Comment: @James: For the sake of speed all modern OSes implement disk drivers as async. So writes can overlap (indeed, in Windows the API for this is called overlapped I/O). It seems that Linux has a more robust implementation of async I/O (partly due to the personal attention from Mr Torvalds himself several years ago when he suddenly became very interested in optimizing Linux disk I/O).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error running node `v4.0.0`, this seemed to happen more often if I had the folder open in windows explorer.

```
fs.js:747
  return binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path),
                 ^
Error: EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\path\folder'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:747:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\path\script.js:88:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I downgraded to node `v0.12.8` and the same process ran smoothly.